# Cannot set configuration when submitting Spark Streaming jobs to YARN with Client within Java code

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

I am finding ways to submit my Spark Streaming jobs to YARN within Java code, and finally decided to use ***org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client*** to submit. Everything looks fine, but now I find I cannot set configurations of either Spark or Spark Streaming, such as `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled`.

I have tried various methods, like setting `SparkConf` which is used to create `JavaSparkContext`, setting `SparkConf` which is used to create `ClientArguments` and `Client`, and using `System.setProperty(xxx)`, but none of them work. I intend to set the configuration dynamically, but even if I modify the **spark-defaults.conf**, nothing changed.

I have also tried other ways to submit jobs, like using `SparkSubmit.main(xxx)` and `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("spark-submit", "xxx")`, but beside this problem, they have even more problems, not seeming like recommended methods.

Could anyone tell me a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SparkLauncher](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/SparkLauncher.html) to run you Spark jobs on Yarn cluster from java code. For example I used it to run my spark jobs from my java web application, spark job jar was packaged into a web app jar.

If you use spark version 1.5 and lower it's going to look like this (see  [SparkLauncher package](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/package-summary.html)):

```
    Process sparkLauncherProcess = new SparkLauncher()
        .setSparkHome(SPARK_HOME)
        .setJavaHome(JAVA_HOME)
        .setAppResource(SPARK_JOB_JAR_PATH)
        .setMainClass(SPARK_JOB_MAIN_CLASS)
        .addAppArgs("arg1", "arg2")
        .setMaster("yarn-cluster")
        .setConf("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true")
        .launch();
     sparkLauncherProcess.waitFor();
```

If you use spark version 1.6 and higher it's going to look like this (see [SparkLauncher package](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/package-summary.html) SparkAppHandle has some additional functionality):

```
    SparkAppHandle handle = new SparkLauncher()
        .setSparkHome(SPARK_HOME)
        .setJavaHome(JAVA_HOME)
        .setAppResource(SPARK_JOB_JAR_PATH)
        .setMainClass(SPARK_JOB_MAIN_CLASS)
        .addAppArgs("arg1", "arg2")
        .setMaster("yarn-cluster")
        .setConf("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true")
        .startApplication();
```

The only dependency you need is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-launcher_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```